# The statistical coffee test

Tags: dataset, interpretation

I have had a couple of courses in mathematics, and two in basic statistics. over the last few days I have pondered on how to perform the best possible test of coffee brands, using my knowledge of statistics and mathematics. Note that the choice of coffee here is completely irregular.

**Background:** My thought was that the standard way is to make each subject taste each coffee and rate them on some scale. Afterwards one can take the mean or average, and maybe remove the most extreme values (outside 95% confidence interval).

I think that this method is easy to implement but lacks a refference point. It is hard for the subjects to objectively compare 6 or 8 types against each other. The important thing is if Y is better than X. Another point is that this does not give any indication on how reliable the subjects score. By removing the extremas you are either labeling the subjects as valid or invalid.

**The experiment:** Given $n$ brands of coffe, have $2n$ cups labeled cup where each brand is in two cups. Give two cups to the subject, make them rate which cup is best, or if they are indistinguishable. Repeat this process untill you have a sufficient sample.

Now the control-rods is the number of tests, where the subject is given two identical brands to compare. If the subject rates A over A, then he/she is unreliable. The subject would then get a credibility factor 5/7 for an example, based on how many of the identical brands he/she was able to identify.

**Statistics**

Now I want to use this data to say something productive of which brand is preffered, where one also takes into consideration how good the subjects are at rating brands.
I was toying around with using a ELO or GLICKO rating system, and then just multiply this rating with the credibility factor. However this is then biased towards the first ranked brands.

**Question** Given a list of ratings between brands, and a credibility factor. What is a good way to interpret and present the dataset?

Comment: On first read, this seems like an example of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/202463) -- it's possible that it might be more productive to ask questions about the underlying issue, rather than about your ideas of a solution. [For example, there's a fair amount of literature on studies of people rating things that usually don't try to quantify reliability, probably because the studies tend to be small (you can only have a rater try so many drinks before you make them unreliable) so that estimating reliability on top of preference may introduce noise rather than reduce it.]

Comment: I like to ask questions that drive physical actions.  If you are a coffee vendor then you could increase prices, or try to make a higher quality cup of coffee.  I thought that [this](https://www.ted.com/talks/malcolm_gladwell_on_spaghetti_sauce?language=en) was fun.

Comment: This sounds a bit like Fisher's Tea cup experiment:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_tasting_tea

Answer (score 2):

I think that using Elo or [Glicko](http://www.glicko.net/glicko/glicko.pdf) is a good choice, but *multiplication for rating* is incorrect. *Credibility factor* affects every single 'match' between brands, so a plan should be

- Do the *experiment* with subject A, then repeat with subject B, subject C, and more.
- Set all 'matches' with a different weight due to subject's *credibility factor*.
- Randomize matches' order and insert results in a rating system engine.

If you're interested in use more than in development, [rankade](https://rankade.com), our free ranking system (for sports, games, coffees and more... :) ), has a weight feature that might fit your needs.

In addition, it allows matches with both 2 and 3+ factions, while Elo and Glicko works just for one-on-one (here's a [comparison](https://rankade.com/ree#ranking-system-comparison)). As you said, *it is hard for the subjects to objectively compare 6 or 8 types against each other*, but it should be easy - and useful - comparing 3 or 4 types in each test.